# Led, light replacement to ABB 1062UC-84 dimmer switch?

Tags: switch, led, dimmer-switch

I am trying to find a part to the switch ABB 1062UC-84. Unfortunately, ABB does not seem to have stocks for them.

What is the preferred way to replace burnout switch with dimmer light when they burn out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These switches are not meant to be taken apart and repaired if something breaks or burns out in them. Doing so would void any warranties on the switch and also hinder any safety precautions built into them. Call their customer service to check on guarantees and if none, the safest and wisest solution is to replace the switch. Good luck and stay safe out there.

Answer (score 1):

So I get it, you grew up with incandescents.  And the incandescent bulb failed and you replace the bulb.  And I'm sure you dealt with fluorescents, and the fluorescent bulb fails and you replace the bulb.

It's easy to reach the conclusion that "all things which emit light fail frequently and are socketed and changeable for that reason".

That is not actually true.  LED is a semiconductor emitter, and it acts like a semiconductor, not a bulb.  It fails at the rate electronics fail.  And if it has failed, it is just as likely that the LED is actually fine, but the electronics behind it has failed.

So if you unsoldered the old LED, you may find it bench-tests just fine, and the problem is on the board somewhere in a capacitor or IC.  Now you're deep-diving into a highly skilled, technical task *that I bet you don't know how to do*.  So now we need a specialist, and now we're getting into real money.  We quickly exceed the value of the switch.